# Unable to retrieve Asset RecordType in APEX but in workbench

Tags: apex, record-type, asset

I am unable to retrieve Asset RecordTypes when I call following method in my apex code:

```
Utils.getRecordTypeBySObjectType('Asset').get('Auto').Id
```

It throws NullPointerException. It works for other standard and custom objects and able to retrieve RecordTypes.

Apex Method:

```
public Static Map<String, RecordType> getRecordTypeBySObjectType(String sobjectType) {
        Map<String, RecordType> mapRecordType = new Map<String, RecordType>();
        List<RecordType> recordTypeList = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType =: sobjectType];
        for ( RecordType itrRecordType : recordTypeList )
            mapRecordType.put(itrRecordType.DeveloperName, itrRecordType);
        return mapRecordType;
 }
```

I know nothing wrong with code but not sure if its related to data issue.

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a `RecordType` whose `SObjectType='Asset'` and whose `DeveloperName='Auto'`?

Comment: Yes I am sure and its working from workbench and returning the Id as well but not working in my code.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your workbench query as evidence.

Comment: Won't be able to include it as I had to mock it up to put in this forum. But believe me its working. Any idea if something to do with data sharing or any config that I am missing here.

Comment: I ran this exact code and it worked as expected.  I received no error so it has to be something data related.  I created a record type of 'Auto' on Asset and ran the code and output the Id into a debug ran from Anonymous Apex and I received no error.

Answer (score 2):

Your version of the class needs to be API version 38 or above.  Salesforce added Record Types to Assets in the Spring '15 release.

The [release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_assets_record_types.htm) pertaining to Record Types and Assets.

Comment: That would be compile time error. My Apex Class API version is 40.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that the `map` coming back from `Utils.getRecordTypeBySObjectType('Asset')` doesn't contain the key 'Auto'.

You should first check if the map contains the 'Auto' key before trying to get the corresponding `Id`.

---

Also, as [@JRiffe answered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194397/102), check that the actual transaction originated from a v38.0+ API version. In theory it is enough that the Utils class is on v40.0, but it would pay to back track through the preceding class versions as well.